# Can't read app.config appSettings from unit test in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, app-config, xunit, rider

I am using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"]` to retrieve values from `app.config` appSettings

```xml
 <appSettings>
    <add key="someKey" value="value" />
    ...
```

However, when I use this in my unit tests, the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` collection is empty.

**This happens only when I run the tests from `JetBrains Rider` IDE!

Running them from `Visual Studio` (even with ReSharper runner) works perfectly fine and values are loaded.**

It is a .Net 5 project using XUnit framework.

What is going on with Rider here?

Answer (score 2):

1. First make sure the app.config is in the correct format. since you want to reference `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"]`

the app.config should be structed this way

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="someKey" value="value" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

2. Add the following lines in project file so that it copies the app.config to be findable by the Resharper test runner. VS may be doing this itself, however Rider seems to need it done explicitly

   ```
    <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" \>
        <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)/ReSharperTestRunner.dll.config" />
    <Target/>
   ```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, this one was the ticket for me. I found there may already be a `Copy` block here with it being copied somewhere else to get around https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22101 Not sure if there's some relationship with this issue.